# Adding multiple (don't know how many) words into the database using explode (php)

Tags: php, foreach, tags, explode

A user can add multiple tags to describe the picture, separate them with commas. I don't know how to split tags and add them into the database, because I can't tell how many words he would write. I know I should use functions count and foreach, but I don't know how.

```
$tag_title=mysql_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['tag_title']);
$array_title=explode(',', $tag_title);
```

Any help would be much appreciated ...

Comment: This spilts tag go into 1 column on your db?

Comment: In database I have a table tags with 2 columns:
tags_id and tags_name

Comment: So you want each tags have own id ?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() expecting first argument unescaped string not connection string. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this simple approach.

```
$s = 'a, b, c, d, e, f, g';
$e = explode(',', $s);
$sum = count($e);
for($i = 0; $i < $sum; $i++)
{
    echo $e[$i];
}
```

Output: `a b c d e f g`

So now you have separated string, this will be your sql query values. And insert its as much as the tags. `$sum` already covering how many insert will be processed.

And of course a note:

> Warning This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works, but I still don't know how to add them into the db that they would be separated (when I add them it's still a string in one row) ...

Comment: You have to put your insert query inside the loop. so its running the query as much as $sum. Thats way you will have them separated.